# Can i control if a column need to be shown inside New form based on Content Type

Tags: 2013, powershell, content-type, list-form, site-column

I am working on an on-premises sharepoint 2013. now i know that i can hide certain columns from New list forms using this power-shell script:-

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://*******/
$field = $web.Fields["Approve"]
$field.ShowInNewForm = $false 
$field.update($true)
```

this will always hide the site column named "Approve" from the New list forms. but in my case i have 2 site content types, which are using the Approve site column.but i want the column to be shown inside the New form for Content Type A, while to be hidden inside the New form for Content Type B .. is this possible? or hiding/showing site columns based on the list form type (New,Edit,View), can only be achieved @ the site column itself? and not at the Content type level ? keeping in mind that in both cases i want the Approve site column, to be shown inside the Edit form..so hiding the column completely from the Content Type will not work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Client side rendering(jsLink)` to control its display based on Content Type.

Just add the below jslink in your newform and editform, modify it to use your content type. Should work.

```
(function () {

    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {        
        "Approve": {
            "NewForm": hideField,
            "EditForm": hideField
        }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();


function hideField(ctx) {

    if(ctx.CurrentItem.ContentType == "Content Type B"){
        // get the span that represents the field's actual edit control
        var span = $get(ctx.FormUniqueId + ctx.FormContext.listAttributes.Id + ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name);

        // still need to go up two levels to hide the entire <tr>
        span.parentNode.parentNode.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
        return "";
    }else{
        return SPFieldBoolean_Edit(ctx);
    }
}
```

Here, i am assuming that `Approve` is a site column of boolean type.

Modified from - [Hiding Forms; fields using standard jquery versus using JSlink. which approach is better](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/145040/8068)

Comment: hey @johng- did you try this approach ?